# What command shows all of the topics and offsets of partitions in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm looking for a Kafka command that shows all of the topics and offsets of partitions. If it's dynamically would be perfect. Right now I'm using java code to see these information, but it's very inconvenient.

Comment: If you have Java code that does this, can you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588389/how-to-monitor-application-processing-of-kafka-messages-for-load-testing/31717142) of mine?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) ships with some tools you can use to accomplish this.

List topics:

```
# ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
test_topic_1
test_topic_2
...
```

List partitions and offsets:

```
# ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --broker-info --group test_group --topic test_topic --zookeeper localhost:2181
Group           Topic                  Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
test_group      test_topic             0   698020          698021          1              test_group-0
test_group      test_topic             1   235699          235699          0               test_group-1
test_group      test_topic             2   117189          117189          0               test_group-2
```

### Update for 0.9 (and higher) consumer APIs

If you're using the [new apis](https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#newconsumerapi), there's a new tool you can use: `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`.

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group count_errors --describe
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
count_errors                   logs                           2          2908278         2908278         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.55
count_errors                   logs                           3          2907501         2907501         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.43
count_errors                   logs                           4          2907541         2907541         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.177
count_errors                   logs                           1          2907499         2907499         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.115
count_errors                   logs                           0          2907469         2907469         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.126
```

Comment: Thanks chrsblck, if I just wanna see the max(latest) offset of each partition no matter which comsumerGroup, how should I issue the command please.

Comment: @chrsblck:-> Same query if i fire from Window Command Prompt , It throughing Error.  COMMAND:--> bin\windows\kafka-run-class.bat kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --broker-info --topic test --zookeeper localhost:2181.   ERROR:--> Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker

Comment: "bash: ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh: No such file or directory" doesn't work at all

Comment: How I do it on Windows?

Comment: Where does this kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker argument come from?

Answer (score 20):

If anyone is interested, you can have the the offset information for all the consumer groups with the following command:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --all-groups --describe
```

The parameter --all-groups is [available](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7471) from Kafka 2.4.0

Comment: Does it work for vanilla Kafka? What version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: Thanks. Kafka 2.1.* doesn't know about this option. Looks like the new feature - you can mention your version of Kafka at post

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexK, I've edited my answer adding the correct version from which the parameter is available.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to try [kt](https://github.com/fgeller/kt). It's also quite faster than the bundled `kafka-topics`.

This is the current most complete info description you can get out of a topic with kt:

`kt topic -brokers localhost:9092 -filter my_topic_name -partitions -leaders -replicas`

It also outputs as JSON, so you can pipe it to `jq` for further flexibility.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The link provided in the comment (you can click on "kt") has a very comprehensive readme. Has install instructions and many examples. If this doesn't answer your question, could you please clarify what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

We're using Kafka 2.11 and make use of this tool - `kafka-consumer-groups`.

```
$ rpm -qf /bin/kafka-consumer-groups
confluent-kafka-2.11-1.1.1-1.noarch
```

For example:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --describe --group logstash | grep -E "TOPIC|filebeat"
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
TOPIC            PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST             CLIENT-ID
beats_filebeat   0          20003914484     20003914888     404             logstash-0-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX /192.168.1.1   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   1          19992522286     19992522709     423             logstash-0-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX /192.168.1.1   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   2          19990597254     19990597637     383             logstash-0-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX /192.168.1.1   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   7          19991718707     19991719268     561             logstash-0-YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY /192.168.1.2   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   8          20015611981     20015612509     528             logstash-0-YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY /192.168.1.2   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   5          19990536340     19990541331     4991            logstash-0-ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ /192.168.1.3   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   6          19990728038     19990733086     5048            logstash-0-ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ /192.168.1.3   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   3          19994613945     19994616297     2352            logstash-0-AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA /192.168.1.4   logstash-0
beats_filebeat   4          19990681602     19990684038     2436            logstash-0-AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA /192.168.1.4   logstash-0
```

#### Random Tip

**NOTE:** We use an alias that overloads `kafka-consumer-groups` like so in our `/etc/profile.d/kafka.sh`:

```
alias kafka-consumer-groups="KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS=\"-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$HOME/.kafka_client_jaas.conf\"  kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server ${KAFKA_HOSTS} --command-config /etc/kafka/security-enabler.properties"
```